# Dynamic height parent div and disobedient children

Tags: html, css, overflow, parent-child

How to prevent the height of a child div overflowing its parent?

My div is reused throughout my website with variable content.
I know setting a height value for the parent will fix this issue but I do not wish to do this as sometimes it is very small.

I have looked at many of the questions related to this problem on here but cannot find a solution that fits my problem.

```
.Parent{
    background: #eee;
    position: relative;
    max-height: 80%;
    max-width: 80%;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
    margin: auto;
    padding: 5px;
    display: inline-block;
}
.Child{
    overflow: auto;
}
```

**DESIRED OUTCOME**

Parent div to have a height that equals its content.

Child div to have scroll if parent div exceeds max-height of 80%.

**DEMO**

http://jsfiddle.net/QtyNU/

Comment: Thank you both I am aware of using overflow on the mentioned div. What I would like though is for the scroll to be on popbody so as to retain the title while scroll.

Comment: Need to set the height of the popup body. Calculate it with JavaScript.

Comment: Basically you need to scroll only an inner div when the outer one overflows. I fear JavaScript is the only way to do this. But add that requirement in your question and let's see if somebody has a better idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set `overflow:auto` on `.PopInfo`. This will have the scrollbar appear on the right-hand side when it doesn't fit.

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Tyriar/jJe9R/)

```
.PopInfo {
    overflow: auto;
}
```

Comment: Thank you both I am aware of using overflow on the mentioned div. What I would like though is for the scroll to be on popbody so as to retain the title while scroll

Comment: I thought you may have, I was having difficulty getting it going also :) I'll have another look.

Comment: I can't figure it out, it would be trivial with JavaScript but with CSS... The problem is you're constraining height on `.PopInfo` using `max-height` not using a `height` value. So `.PopInfo` is saying `.PopBody`, you take care of my height. Therefore setting `.PopBody` to `min-height:100%` (based on its parent) would create a loop so it does nothing. I'm not sure you can even do this with a variable height message box.

Comment: That's what I was beginning to think. I appreciate your efforts thanks.

Answer (score 0):

From what I see in your fiddle, the problem is the `max-height: 80%` rule. The parent div expands correctly up to that. If you want to scroll after that, you simply have to add

```
overflow: scroll;
```

to the parent CSS. See [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/TfmaS/).

Comment: This works, but you will always have scrollbars. Better use the solution by Daniel with `overflow:auto;`